# Delete files within all directories in a directory

Tags: command-line, directory, rm

I recently needed to delete all the files within ~40 directories that were within a parent directory, without deleting the directories themselves. I ended up manually doing so, but is there a more efficient way of doing this? I.e., is there a linux command that can do this?

For a more clear picture of what I mean:

HomeDirectoryName --> subdirectoryName --> 4 simulation info files

I had the above path, except there are 40 subdirectories, each of which have he 4 simulation files. I needed to delete all the simulation info files without deleting the "subdirectoryName" directories.

It may not be possible, as I searched everywhere for about an hour before finally deciding to do it manually.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182033/remove-all-files-recursively-without-deleting-directories

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why you want to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very simple with the `find` command - just use `-type f` to find only files and not directories

```
find /path/to/parent/directory -type f -delete
```

By default, `find` recurses into subdirectories, so will find all files in the tree from this point down.

Comment: Would that search within the directories in the parent directory as well, or just remove the files in the parent directory?

Comment: that includes parent directory ,too

Answer (score 3):

from parent directory run

```
find -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

for removing each file individually, or alternatively

```
find -type f -exec rm {} +
```

to enqueue multiple files to `rm` at a time.

For python enthusiasts, here's another solution:

```
 python -c 'import os;[os.unlink(os.path.join(r,f)) for r,d,fs in os.walk(".") for f in fs]'
```

Comment: If not using `-delete`, you should at least use `-exec rm -- {} +`, so that `find` doesn't start a new `rm` for each file.

Comment: @muru  that can be done for speed if there's a lot of files in the range of thousands, but in the range of couple hundred files, it won't make much difference.

Comment: You seem to be particularly fond of slow commands.

Comment: @muru  well, I'm not Russian, that's why I'm not rushing ;)

Answer (score 1):

From the parent directory

```
rm */*
```

will remove the 160 simulation info files without removing the 40 directories that contain the files.

(It doesn't matter in this case, but it may be useful in the future to know that `rm` will never remove a directory unless you explicitly ask it to with with `-r` flag.)